# iOS/Android development in HTML5, can we access hardware?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, html, hardware

We have to create an application for iPhone and Android as a school assignment. None of us have any experience with building an iPhone app. We want to create the app with HTML and Javascript. Is it possible to access the hardware using JavaScript? Do we have to build an Android and iPhone app apart from each other so we have another base to build on?

Since I saw a tutorial on Youtube where you use Eclipse to make an Android app as you would always do with the R.view method and related methods.

Instead of importing XML you import HTML5 and CSS but we are afraid we can't access any hardware such as the camera or acceleration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native html app can't access mobile's hardware directly, but you can use [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). It works as intermediate layer between phone OS and HTML app.

Comment: Thanks, we started using Phonegap now, but we can't seem to use an iPhone for some reason? Apple is blocking everything?

Comment: You need to register dev. account at apple com (not free) before you will be able to run your app on iphone (same as for any other native app)

Comment: Yeah, we noticed that. It's pretty stupid that Apple wants to have full control. Android is so much friendlier and easier to use when developing and debugging. I hope we can get a license soon though.